# Bing Map v7, Direct call vs Ajax Call. Delay on Callback Function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery, bing-maps

I'm adding a Bing Map into the page using this call:

```
var geocodeRequest = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=" + encodeURI(AddressString) + "&output=json&jsonp=GeocodeCallback&key=" + credentials;
```

it's working fine when it is used directly in the page javaScript tag. I want to reuse it in different pages so I'm trying to extract a Partial View and call it on demand in different pages using Ajax call.

here is the controller

```
 public ActionResult ShowMap(string address)        
{            
  MapHandlerModel model = new TheList20Site.MapHandlerModel { Title = "Address", Address = address, OriginalHeight = 400, OriginalWidth = 500, SmallHeight = 0, SmallWidth = 500, Speed = 500 };
  return PartialView("prtMap", model);        
}
```

and the call is happen through this ajax method:

```
$.ajax({               
 url: "/Project/ShowMap",   
 type: "Post",                
 data: { address: AddressString },                
 success: function (data) {
      $("#divMapPlaceholder").html(data);
       }
});
```

while I'm using this ajax call there is a significant delay in calling "GeocodeCallback" function so the map is pointg to nowhere but after refreshing the map (not the page) it is working fine!

One more thing ... if I call this partial view using HtmlHelper partial (like the code below) it is working fine...but still I need it to be called on demand (like on completing some form and etc.)

```
 @{        
        @Html.Partial("prtMap", model)    
   }
```

I don't know what is wrong...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might want to look at doing to speed things up is to perform the geocode on the server side. You could do this right in the ShowMap function. You can find information on how to use the Bing Maps REST services in .NET here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx